# Collection which raises exception when exceeding its max size

Tags: python, collections, max-size

Is there a collection which raises exception when exceeding its max size property?

I know it happens in the Queue.Queue object but it did not raise exception when I used collections.deque,  but instead the last element got overridden.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could create a custom wrapper subclassing most suitable collection or build-in type, add a length property and check it before adding new elements by overriding methods.

Comment: When you say "collection" - do you specifically mean a double ended queue?  Or a dictionary?  Or what is it about `Queue` that doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Queue` which raises `queue.Full` if full:

```
>>> import queue
>>> q = queue.Queue(3)
>>> q.put_nowait(1)
>>> q.put_nowait(2)
>>> q.put_nowait(3)
>>> q.put_nowait(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ruediger/data/p3/Python-3.4.2/Lib/queue.py", line 187, in put_nowait
    return self.put(item, block=False)
  File "/Users/ruediger/data/p3/Python-3.4.2/Lib/queue.py", line 133, in put
    raise Full
queue.Full
```

Comment: Thnk you Daniel. But I know this kind of collection, I was wondering if there is any other collection which wil raise a similar exception